# How To Append In The .txt File And Overwriting In Text File

Tags: android, file, text, append

I Am Trying To Save The Incoming Message In .Txt File Sms Is Saving But When The New Sms Come It Is Not Getting Updated Old Sms Is Get Deleted And New Sms Is Shown.
Plz Tell That How To Overwrite In Existing Text File Which Is Generated In This Code.

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
              File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
              File Dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath() + "/FLOW DATA");

    if (!Dir.exists()) {
               Dir.mkdir();
      }
              File file = new File(Dir`enter code here`, "FLOW DATA.txt");
                        try {
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        fileOutputStream.write(message.getBytes());
                        fileOutputStream.close();

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Message Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {                    
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SD CARD NOT FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to append to the file _without_ overwriting the previous messages?

Comment: Please can you write in a normal way?

Comment: How To Append In The .txt File And Overwriting In Text File

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense. May be the language barrier. You don't want the old SMS to be deleted, but you somehow want to overwrite something?

Comment: yes u are write plz help me i am a 8 th grade student

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace this line:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

with this:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true)
```

where if you set boolen true, you say that you want to write appending text.

Comment: if answer help you, maybe can help someone else but you've to quote the answer ;)